# Any dart package that supporting git clone?

Tags: dart

Well probably this, https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/dart/+/a9ad609ab02b033a158bfc2353ea5af24a484a02/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/lib/src/source/git.dart

it seems that is only for google internal.

is there any open dart package to handle git ?

Comment: Did you check https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/git

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Gude!, search result with 'dart git package' cannot find that package from google :/  maybe I should find it from pub.dart.org first.

Comment: Google search still thinks Dart are arrows to throw ;-) There are all available packages in pub.dartlang.org anyway.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of options:

1. [`git` on pub](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/git) - Kevin Moore's wrapper around the Git CLI (as posted in comments by Günter).
2. [Git client written natively in Dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/bleeding_edge/blob/master/dart/sdk/lib/_internal/pub/lib/src/git.dart) - I think this is the one you found; it's not complete, but it powers [Chrome Dev Editor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-dev-editor-develop/pnoffddplpippgcfjdhbmhkofpnaalpg?hl=en) so is actively being developed and will presumably become feature-complete.
3. [`GitHub for Dart` on pub](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/github) - A package by Kenneth Endfinger that wraps the GitHub API (this may or may not do what you want, depending on your exact needs, and ofc whether you're using GitHub)

Answer (score 0):

### rw_git

I've written a small git wrapper on top of [git on pub](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/git) which facilitates the execution of some common `git` commands, `clone` included.

So, for example you could write something as simple as:

```
final localDirectoryName = "RW_GIT";
final repositoryToClone =
      "https://github.com/jasontaylordev/CleanArchitecture";

RwGit rwGit = RwGit();
rwGit.clone(localDirectoryToCloneInto, repositoryToClone);
```

which will create a local repository (if not already exists) and clone inside it the specified repository.

You can then perform various operations on top of the cloned repository such as:

- `rwGit.fetchTags(localRepo)`: Retrieves a `List<String>` of all the tags.
- `rwGit.getCommitsBetween(localRepo, oldTag, newTag)`: Retrieves a `List<String>` that includes all the commits done between the `oldTag` and `newTag`.
- `rwGit.stats(localRepo, oldTag, newTag)`: Retrieves a `ShortStatDto` object that includes information regarding `code insertions`, `code deletions` and `number of changed files`.

## Artifacts

- Available on [rw_git on pub](https://pub.dev/packages/rw_git).
- Contribute on [rw-git on GitHub](https://github.com/gbrandtio/rw-git).